# Use facebook-api to gather data about my profile being mentioned

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get data from facebook-api when my profile was mentioned. The profile might be a fanpage. I would like to get informed whenever my profile is being mentioned.

Graph-api's [{page-id}/tagged](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed) shows all public posts in which my page has been tagged. But there are limitations to this - for example the limit query seems to be 100 posts. And on the other hand there is no way to ask for a specific time-period.

My goal is to gave a graph (posts against time) which would allow me to see when and how often my page was mentioned.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: I see - so that's a way to go threw the results. - But this only allows me to see tagged results - but someone might mention my fb-page without tagging it. Or is the tag automatically added whenever someone mentions a fb-page?